# "while I am dancing" vs "while I dance"

Tags: clauses

Which are more frequently used?

> 1A - I will be discussing the details while you are researching the data.
>
> 1B - I will be discussing the details while you research the data.

and

> 2A - I was cleaning the garage while you were preparing a snack.
>
> 2B - I was cleaning the garage while you prepared a snack.

Is there any wrong?

Comment: No - they are all syntactically correct. In 1A you are talking while he is researching, in 1B you are splitting the tasks between you

Comment: Alright! There is a slight difference then.

Comment: As far as my grammatical knowledge goes, they are both correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On their own:

- "I dance" (simple present tense) suggests dancing is an action you
  regularly perform. The dancing occurs in the present but the specific
  time is not clear.
- "I am dancing" (present continuous tense) suggests
  you are dancing right now.

However, you have the phrase following a while conjunction, which says that the adverbial/second clause is happening at the same time as your main clause. That takes precedence over the time implied by your adverbial clause.

1. Main clause: "I will be discussing the details" << This says the action will happen in the future.
2. Conjunction: "while" << This says that the next clause happens simultaneously with the first clause.
3. Adverbial clause: "you research the data." or "you are researching the data." << This clause is happening at the same time as 1, regardless of the specific time suggested by the tense.

Both are correct and commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

both mean "While I continue to dance" so either would work. All four of your examples are correct. I doubt anyone would know which one is used more frequently.